# We are in public beta!

Tags: discussion, beta

[we have graduated to public beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97295/devops) (So, yayy!)

Congrats to the "beta" badge winners, and also to the ones who "fulfilled" their commitment from Area51.

Also, please share the posts which you think deserve to be shared with the community, and encourage more people to view and participate.  [Also, you'd be getting the shiny "Announcer", "Booster" and "Publicist" badges for helping!]

Congrats to all of us. And, let's work together in making this site a great resource for fellow Devops folks. :)

Comment: Dawny33, how to share? Can you please provide some manual?

Comment: @RomeoNinov See the `share` link under the tags?  Click on it. It'll give you a unique link.  And now, share that unique link :)

Comment: tweet out: https://twitter.com/DanCornilescu/status/844579437064663041

Comment: @DanCornilescu Awesome!  Retweeted :)